# wordpress permalink wrap around block element

Tags: html, wordpress

In Wordpress I am trying to use and anchor tag to wrap around an article using get_Permalink() as the href. Here is my code so far (this is within a loop).

```
echo '<a href="' .get_permalink(). '">';
    echo '<article class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 port-box"> <!-- portflio article box -->'; 
            the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive') );
                echo '<div class="port-details focus-box">';
                    echo'<h3 class="latestnews-title red-border-bottom"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>';
                        echo'<p>'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Portfolio-type', true).'</p>';
                        echo '<p>';
                            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Details', true);
                        echo '</p>';
                    echo '</div>';                                  
                echo '</article>';
            echo '</a>';
```

When I Look at the output code it shows an anchor tag being output, but the permalink does not place the url into the href.

Is it possible to wrap a article in a "a" tag? If so does anyone have some guidence on how to make it work.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try get the link by

```
get_permalink ( $post->ID );
```

and your code will be

```
    <?php $link = get_permalink ( $post->ID ); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link ?>">
        <article class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 port-box">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive') ); ?>
            <div class="port-details focus-box">
            <h3 class="latestnews-title red-border-bottom"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Portfolio-type', true) ?></p>
            <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Details', true); ?></p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </a>
```

***( try use this way its much clean and keep html as html and php as php and easy to read and debug )

Comment: Thi worked! with the exception that i needed to lose the "var" in the first php line.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the first line:

`echo '<a href="' .get_permalink(). '">';`

To:

`echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">';`

As you are using `$post->ID` to get the post ID in that bit of code. More on [`get_permalink`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/).

Comment: Thanks for the help! When i try running this code i get an error for invalid var. One thing I forgot to mention that probably makes a big difference is, the loop is not looking for posts by rather pages with a particular template. With that said would i need to change " ( $post->ID ) " to something else?